# Mocking OSX's Terminal listing style ls -la in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: macos, ubuntu, command-line, terminal, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to get an output that looks like `ls -la` in my mac terminal, but in Ubuntu. It follows the following listing order:

- Files and Directories that start with a dot . (coloring the directories)
- Folders
- Files
  So far, `ls -lahpXr --color` works (with a slight size format modification), but the files are being shown at the top along the dot directories and files.

Does anyone know how to bring all the files to the bottom? I got that combo by checking the man pages man ls in Ubuntu 16.04.

Any help is much appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--group-directories-first` option:

```sh
ls --group-directories-first -la
```

This will first list all directories (hidden and visible) and then all files.

For convenience I would suggest to set an alias for that, as there is no short option for that:

```sh
alias ls='ls --group-directories-first'
```